# ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER can't see all View

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL DEVELOPER does not list all the views I can see thru 
    select * from all_views

Why I can see the view using the query builder and the Sql Developer do not show the views on the left pane?

I already checked the option 'include synonyms' from the filter.

I am not the owner of the view.

**EDITED**:

I found the answer with the help of  Glenn and Sean

The answer is:

1 - you have to go to your oracle conection

2 - right click and select 'Schema Browser'

3- Now you can select the schema and see the views it have.

Regards

Comment: The object browser is by schema. Go up a level to the appropriate schema and look for views under there.

Comment: The user I am using can only see this schema...

Comment: Hi you was right. I am new with oracle sql developer and not understood what you tell me before. Now I see you was correct since beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all_views (as well as the other "all_*" tables) only show entries in your schema or that you have access to.  dba_views will show all views in the database.  Your user probably does not have read access to the view via direct grants to your user or granted through a role.

all_views - all views you have access to + views in your user's schema
user_views - all views in your user's schema
dba_views - all views in the database

Comment: Do you know if there are a way to a limited user see the schema it have only read access?

Comment: I don't know of a way for you to see if the view exists, but not be able to select it.  You should just need to grant reads to the objects you want to see.  grant select on {schema.viewname} to {user}.  Alternatively, you can create a role, grant read on all objects in that schema you want to see to that role.  Grant your user that role.  grant {role} to {user}.

Comment: If I do a SELECT * FROM SOME_USER_VIEW_NAME. I got the results in the SQL Developer. But this SOME_USER_VIEW_NAME does not shows in objects browser. And I only have this user and I can't ask the DBA more permission....

Comment: I'm assuming you're in PL/SQL Developer by All-Around Automation.  You should have an Object Browser on the left or right side of the screen.  There should be a drop down near the top that has schema's in it.  Try changing that to the schema the view is in.  Then expand the views folder.